# Using LINQ to group on ID, EmailListID, PhoneListID, etc

Tags: c#, sql, linq, grouping, dapper

- I'm using Dapper to map my database content to `EmployeeModel` objects.
- The mapping of properties is working, but the grouping at the end is still giving me trouble:

  - `EmployeeModel` takes `List<PhoneModel>` and `List<EmployeeModel>` as properties.
  - Items are grouped according to `EmployeeID`, however multiple email and phone results are returned as I haven't been able to find the syntax for doing so.
  - I've tried looping through the `EmployeeIDs` in the `employeeList` after it's been grouped by `ID`, before it's been grouped by `ID`, and while it's being grouped by `ID`.

```cs
var sql = @"

SELECT
    e.id,
    e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Nickname, 
    em.id as ID, em.Address, em.Type, 
    jt.id as ID, jt.Name, 
    e.id as ID, p.Number, p.Type,
    d.id as ID, d.Name,
    es.id as ID, es.Name 

FROM
    dbo.Employees e 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Emails         em ON em.EmployeeID  = e.id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.JobTitles      jt ON e.JobTitleID   = jt.id
    LEFT JOIN Phones             p  ON p.EmployeeID   = e.id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Departments    d  ON e.DepartmentID = d.id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.EmployeeStatus es ON e.StatusID     = es.id
";

IEnumerable<EmailModel> emailsGrouped = new List<EmailModel>();

var employees = await connection
    .QueryAsync<
        EmployeeModel,EmailModel,TitleModel,
        PhoneModel,DepartmentModel,StatusModel,
        EmployeeModel>
    (
        sql,
        ( e, em, t, p, d, s ) =>
        {
            e.EmailList.Add(em);
            e.JobTitle = t;
            e.PhoneList.Add(p);
            e.Department = d;
            e.Status = s;
            return e;
       },
        splitOn: "ID, ID, ID, ID, ID"
    );


foreach (EmployeeModel emod in employees)
{
    emod.EmailList.GroupBy(em => em.ID);
}
            
var result = employees
    .GroupBy(e => e.ID)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var groupedEmployee = g.First();
        groupedEmployee.EmailList = g.Select(e => e.EmailList.Single()).ToList();
        groupedEmployee.PhoneList = g.Select(e => e.PhoneList.Single()).ToList();
    
        return groupedEmployee;
    });

return result.ToList();
```

Here is my Email definition, as requested.  It's inside my EmployeeClass, so I've posted the whole thing.

```
public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
        public TitleModel JobTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
        public StatusModel Status { get; set; }
        public List<EmailModel> EmailList { get; set; } = new List<EmailModel>();
        public List<PhoneModel> PhoneList { get; set; } = new List<PhoneModel>();
        public List<RestrictionModel> RestrictionsList { get; set; } = new List<RestrictionModel>();
        public List<CitationModel> CitationsList { get; set; } = new List<CitationModel>();
        public List<CertificationModel> CertificationList { get; set; } = new List<CertificationModel>();

        public string ListView
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
            }
        }
        public string ToEmailString()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> employeeEmailStrings = EmailList.Select(emmod => emmod.ToString());
            string employeeEmailString = string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}", employeeEmailStrings);
            return $"{FirstName}, {LastName}: {Environment.NewLine} -{JobTitle.Name}- {Environment.NewLine}";
        }

        //IEnumerable<string> phoneStrings = PhoneList.Select(plistmod => plistmod.ToString());
        //string phoneString = string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}", phoneStrings);



        public string ToCertificationString()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> certificationStrings = CertificationList.Select(clistmod => clistmod.ToString());
            string certificationString = string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}", certificationStrings);
            return certificationString;
        }
        public class EmailModel
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Address} ({Type})";
            }
        }
        public class PhoneModel
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Number} ({Type})";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying now is to loop through the Emails in the `EmployeeModel` to create a new list of emails, and then set that new list as the `EmployeeModel.List<EmailModel>`.

Comment: That almost looks like a repetition of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65772230/861716). IMO, Dapper isn't the best tool for this. If you want to query complex object graphs, use an ORM like Entity Framework.

Comment: What is the proper procedure for asking a similar question when no adequate answer has been provided and the code has changed to reflect user suggestions?  Should I update or delete the OP?  And I appreciate your comment about Dapper not being the best tool for this and that Entity Framework would be more appropriate.  It sounds, then, like the modeling I'm trying to accomplish doesn't have a standardized syntax in Dapper or Linq.

Comment: I don't see why you don't just do the grouping in SQL. That would be far, far simpler.

Comment: @Dai, I don't believe the results I'm looking for are achievable by grouping first in Sql, but if you can think of a way, I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @JoshuaWhite One moment. Also, I've just edited the code in your question so that it's more readable.

Comment: @JoshuaWhite What is the multiplicity of the relationships between the tables?

Comment: @JoshuaWhite What is the definition of `EmailModel`?

Comment: I noticed your posted code has a `return` inside the `foreach` - that can't be right. Did you mean to post two, separate code blocks?

Comment: You really shouldn't have a `Model` suffix on every entity type. It's going to lead to confusion when you use ViewModels and DTOs (and Entity Types should never be used directly as ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC/Core for security reasons I won't go into, nor should they be used as DTOs due to the horrors of Json.NET+LazyLoading bringing a server to its knees).

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting.  
-The database is normalized as much as I could manage, so the relationships include one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many.  For instance, the Emails table contains the FK from the Employees table, and there the CitationsRecord table takes FKs from Employee table and the CitationType table.  I'm using one query (which I'll make a stored procedure once I have everything working), and mapping all employee model information.  Many of the EmployeeModel properties are lists, such as Emails, Phones, Citations, etc.

-I'll update OP with EmailModel def.

Comment: -The return inside the foreach was the result of copy-paste that went awry and which I failed to delete.  I'll update.

-The Model suffix was recommended by a guy on YouTube named Tim Corey.  I've been following his tutorials for a couple of months.  It's how he defines all his classes.  I'll most likely remove those suffixes as I learn more.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I don't see any advantage to moving the SQL to a stored-procedure. Is there a reason you want to do that? The advantage of having the full SQL directly within your application code is that you know exactly what will be queried - whereas if the SQL is in a stored-procedure then the sproc could be edited and break your consuming applications.

Comment: I thought it was always best practice to keep SQL out of your code and in stored procedures.  This, I'm told, ensures the front and back ends are totally independent of one another.  Whenever I post code including a query, someone inevitably tells me it should be in a stored procedure.

Comment: @JoshuaWhite Separation of the front-end and back-end is important, yes - but when there is a separation there needs to be a clearly-defined interface, and **the interface to a database is SQL**. People who mindlessly advocate for moving queries from application code to stored-procedures are practicing [Cargo-Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) (also stored-procedures should not be used for operations involving only `SELECT` queries, that's what `VIEW` and UDFs are for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you're actually trying to load an *object-graph* (containing nodes of distinct types) from a database using SQL - and you're trying to do that using a single query.

**That won't work**. (Naïve, single-query) SQL is not suitable for querying object-graphs. This is why ORMs exist. However with some RDBMS-specific SQL extensions (e.g. T-SQL, PL/SQL, etc) to execute a query batch you *can* return an object-graph from a database.

The good news is that Dapper supports this scenario with `QueryMultiple` - however as far as I know it won't map collection properties, so you need to do that manually (so read on!)

(I note that Entity Framework, specifically, will generate single-`SELECT` queries that return redundant data in columns that represent lower-multiplicity data - this has its trade-offs but *generally speaking* separate queries can work faster overall with the right tweaks (such as using a table-valued variable to hold `KEY` values instead of re-evaluating the same `WHERE` criteria for every query in the batch - as always, check your indexes, `STATISTICS` objects, and execution plans!).

---

When querying for an object-graph, you'll write a `SELECT` query batch where each query returns *all* objects of the same type that has a `JOIN` with any other entities with a `1:1` or `1:0..1` multiplicity (if it isn't more efficient to load them in a separate query in the same batch).

In your case, I see you have:

```
[Employees]---(1:m)---[Phones]
[Employees]---(1:m)---[Emails]

[JobTitles]---(1:m)---[Employees]
[Departments]---(1:m)---[Employees]
[EmployeeStatus]---(1:m)---[Employees]        // is this an enum table? if so, you can probably ditch it
```

So try this:

- For the sake of simplicity, `JobTitles`, `Departments`, and `EmployeeStatus` can be done in a single query.
- I assume the foreign-key columns are `NOT NULL` so an `INNER JOIN` should be used instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
const String EMPLOYEES_PHONES_EMAILS_SQL = @"

-- Query 1: Employees, Departments, EmployeeStatuses
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.Nickname,
    t.Name AS JobTitleName, -- This is to disambiguate column names. Never rely on column ordinals!
    d.Name AS DepartmentName,
    s.Name AS StatusName
FROM
    dbo.Employees AS e
    INNER JOIN dbo.JobTitles      AS t ON e.JobTitleID   = t.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.Departments    AS d ON e.DepartmentId = d.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeStatus AS s ON e.StatusID     = s.id;

-- Query 2: Phones
SELECT
    p.EmployeeId,
    p.Number,
    p.Type
FROM
    dbo.Phones AS p;

-- Query 3: Emails
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.EmployeeId,
    m.Address,
    m.Type
FROM
    dbo.Emails AS m;
";

using( SqlMapper.GridReader rdr = connection.QueryMultiple( EMPLOYEES_PHONES_EMAILS_SQL ) )
{
    List<EmployeeModel>          employees          = ( await rdr.ReadAsync<EmployeeModel>() ).ToList();
    var phonesByEmployeeId = ( await rdr.ReadAsync<PhoneModel>   () ).GroupBy( p => p.EmployeeId ).Dictionary( grp => grp.Key grp => grp.ToList() );
    var emailsByEmployeeId = ( await rdr.ReadAsync<EmailModel>   () ).GroupBy( m => m.EmployeeId ).Dictionary( grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList() );

    foreach( EmployeeModel emp in employees )
    {
        if( phonesByEmployeeId.TryGetValue( emp.EmployeeId, out var phones ) )
        {
            emp.Phones.AddRange( phones );
        }
        
        if( emailsByEmployeeId.TryGetValue( emp.EmployeeId, out var emails ) )
        {
            emp.Emails.AddRange( emails );
        }
    }
}
```

I'll admit that I'm not intimately familiar with Dapper - and **there is a problem with the code above**: it doesn't instruct Dapper how to read the included `Department`, `JobTitleModel`, and `EmployeeStatus` data in the first query. I assume there's some overload of `ReadAsync` to specify other included data.

If you find yourself doing this kind of logic repetitively you can define your own extension-methods to handle the worst parts (such as `GroupBy().ToDictionary()`, and populating a collection property from a dictionary of loaded entities).

---

If you had a filter criteria, then you'd need to either store the resultant `EmployeeId` key values in a TVV, or repeat the criteria on `Employees` as the right-hand-side of an `INNER JOIN` in the queries for `Phones` and `Emails`.

For example, if you wanted to add an ability to find all Employees (and their phone-numbers and e-mail addresses) by name, you'd do this:

```
const String EMPLOYEES_PHONES_EMAILS_SQL = @"

-- Query 0: Get EmployeeIds:
DECLARE @empIds TABLE ( EmpId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO @empIds ( EmpId )
SELECT
    EmployeeId
FROM
    dbo.Employees
WHERE
    FirstName LIKE @likeFirst
    OR
    LastName LIKE @likeLast;

-- Query 1: Employees, Departments, EmployeeStatuses
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.Nickname,
    t.Name AS JobTitleName, -- This is to disambiguate column names. Never rely on column ordinals!
    d.Name AS DepartmentName,
    s.Name AS StatusName
FROM
    dbo.Employees AS e
    INNER JOIN dbo.JobTitles      AS t ON e.JobTitleID   = t.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.Departments    AS d ON e.DepartmentId = d.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeStatus AS s ON e.StatusID     = s.id

    INNER JOIN @empIds AS i ON i.EmpId = e.EmployeeId;

-- Query 2: Phones
SELECT
    p.EmployeeId,
    p.Number,
    p.Type
FROM
    dbo.Phones AS p
    INNER JOIN @empIds AS i ON i.EmpId = p.EmployeeId;

-- Query 3: Emails
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.EmployeeId,
    m.Address,
    m.Type
FROM
    dbo.Emails AS m
    INNER JOIN @empIds AS i ON i.EmpId = m.EmployeeId;
";

using( SqlMapper.GridReader rdr = connection.QueryMultiple( EMPLOYEES_PHONES_EMAILS_SQL, new { likeFirst = "%john%", likeLast = "%smith%" } ) )
{
    // same as before
}
```